# Custom WCF service - namespace location problem

Tags: web-services, wcf, domain, wsdl

I created a custom web service in my sharepoint using CSKDev template. Everything looks good when I'm testing my service locally. But problems came up when I decided to test it on our sample farm with Internet access.

Assuming we have local domain named `foo.local`, and two load-balanced servers - web1 and web2. Our site can be accessed from outside via eg. `sharepoint.foo.com`. The problem is that when I try to access service metadata, I find that additional wsdl schemas are pointing locally, not externally, eg. accessing site `http://sharepoint.foo.com/_vti_bin/IntegrationServices/PortalMessageService.svc/mex`

results in wsdl with reference to:

```
<xsd:import schemaLocation="https://web1.foo.local/_vti_bin/IntegrationServices/PortalMessageService.svc/mex?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
```

web1.foo.local is not accessible from Internet, so how to fix this? What should I do to make additional schemas available by the external address of our portal?

### **EDIT 1:**

When I open my service metadata with WcfTestClient and open Client.dll.config, I can see three bindings looking the same and three endpoints where only first has configured address.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [endpoint address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx) and see if defining it to sharepoint.foo.com does the trick.

Also I ran into [this](http://forums.asp.net/p/1096811/1659596.aspx) where you have multiple suggestions, specifically instructions in how to configure the endpoint of the mex.

Comment: I don't have any XML configuration at all since sharepoint does all the configuration. I also can't change host header because I have and SSL binding with certificate without wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

This was the same problem with ASP.NET WSDL web services in SharePoint 2007, and why originally you had to create custom WSDL generation pages. This has been fixed in SharePoint 2010 by using SharePoint service factories.

If you are using the Microsoft SharePoint web service factories, the root domain should not be a problem as the WSDL generation for the endpoint is dynamic based on the URL when accessing the service. Check my blog post to see how to use the out-of-box service factories.

http://blog.sharepointbits.com/2010/04/custom-wcf-services-in-sharepoint-2010_17.html

Comment: I'm aware of these factories and since I created my on template provided by CKSDev, `MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory` is used and yet this issue is present...

Comment: How are your zones configured? Do you have each Url associated with a zone on an extended web application, or are both zones on the same IIS virtual directory?

Comment: I have one web application (no extended web application). My zones are: Default - https://sharepoint.foo.local, Intranet - 10.48.1.20 - load-balancer cluster address, Internet - https://sharpoint.foo.com, Ekstranet - https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (public IP address)

Comment: I think your approach of multiple zones mapped to the same virtual web application may be at the root of the problem. The Service Host factory is using the URL of the default zone within the context of the virtual web application. I would suggest extending the web application for a zone, instead of using alternate access mappings with the same default web application.

Comment: I'll try this out and come back to share results with you.